# Custom AuthenticationProvider ignore sessionManagement

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

I wrote custom AuthenticationProvider and it work. I follow [this tutorial](http://javainsimpleway.com/spring/spring-security-using-custom-authentication-provider/).

I'm also use HttpSecurity configuration like this.

```
http
....
....
.sessionManagement()
     .sessionFixation().migrateSession()
     .maximumSessions(1)
     .expiredUrl("/expired")
     .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
     .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
    ;
```

But user still can login twise and more.

As a comparison, inMemoryAuthentication and jdbcAuthentication working. Only AuthenticationProvider is not.

Comment: Is your custom AuthenticationProvider returning an Authentication with any custom objects (i.e. do you have a custom Authentication implementation, a custom object for the principal, etc)? If so, ensure you have implemented hashCode and equals properly

Comment: Owh, that's the problem.
It works now. Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom Authentication,  UserDetails, or principal for the Authentication ensure to implement hashCode and equals methods.